# Generic Form Opener

Tags: winforms, generics, user-controls

I am trying to create a new user control as a generic lookup form opener.

```
lkpControl.FormToOpen="FrmProductList";
lkpControl.ReturnValueVariableName="ProductCode";
lkpControl.ShowThatForm();
if dialog result is OK:
lkpControl.txtValue=lkpControl.GetSelectedValue();
```

this control will open preconfigured (or specified in design time) form from its name and will return the selected item in opened form back to its textbox. Simply like getting the path from folder browser dialog.

simply a generic form opener and value getter of selected item in opened form.

I would appreciate if you could direct me to any solution or a path to follow.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I've solved it by this:

```
public partial class LookupButton : UserControl
{
    [Description("Type of the Form To Open: typeof(LookupButtonTest.Form2)")]
    [Category("Custom")]
    public Type FormToOpen { get; set; }
    [Description("Name Of the public property to get return value from opened form.")]
    [Category("Custom")]
    public string PropertyToGet { get; set; }
    public LookupButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormToOpen == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FormToOpen");
        }

        if (PropertyToGet.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("PropertyToGet");
        }

        Form objForm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(FormToOpen);

        if (objForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bool propertyFound = false;
            PropertyInfo[] props = objForm.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
            {
                if (p.Name == PropertyToGet)
                {
                    txtReturnVal.Text = p.GetValue(objForm, null).ToString();
                    propertyFound = true;
                }
            }
            if (!propertyFound)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("PropertyToGet");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static class ShowFormAs
   {
       public static T1 ShowForm<T1>(string fullTypeName, string propertyName)
           where T1: class
       {
           return string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullTypeName) 
               ? default(T1) : 
               ShowForm<T1>(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(fullTypeName) as Form, propertyName);
       }

       public static T1 ShowForm<T, T1>(string propertyName)
           where T: Form, new ()
           where T1: class 
       {
           return ShowForm<T1>(new T(), propertyName);
       }

       private static T1 ShowForm<T1>(Form form, string propertyName)
           where T1: class 
       {
           if (form == null)
           {
               return default(T1);
           }

           if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               var property = form.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(o => string.CompareOrdinal(o.Name, propertyName) == 0);

               if (property == null)
               {
                   return default(T1);
               }

               return property.GetValue(form, null) as T1;
           }

           return default(T1);
       }
   }
```

Usage:

```
var x = ShowFormAs.ShowForm<Form2, string>("TTT");
var z = ShowFormAs.ShowForm<string>("StackOverflow.Form2", "TTT");
```

The Form2 class is:

```
 namespace StackOverflow
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public string TTT { get { return "Ololo"; } }
        }
    }
```

And result is:

[image]